# How to add values to the JSON from UI using AngualJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

HTML:

```
 <button class="btn-success" ng-click="addEvent(item)">Sumbit</button>
```

Controller code is here (I am using Angular):

```
 $scope.events = [
  { "title": "Deployment", "start": "5/7/2015 11:23 AM" },


  { "title": "Go to Task", "start": new Date(y, m, 28), "end": new Date(y, m, 29) }
];
 $scope.addEvent = function (item) {
    //item.$save();
    //$scope.item.color = "black";
    $scope.calEventsExt.events.push(item);

   // $scope.item = {};

};
```

In this JSON I want to add new item which will come from Ui and it should display and add into the Ui.

Here What's happening when i add in the Ui its getting added but when i refresh the screen the value goes out means its only bound to the scope not to the element.

So how to fix this. I am beginner in angular. Please help.

Comment: html is <button class="btn-success" ng-click="addEvent(item)">Sumbit</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured out what the problem is, you only add the new item to a scope variable. In order to achieve what you want you have to persist your data somewhere (e.g. on a server or even local storage). Otherwhise it will never be saved and you always get the $scope.events element you described above.

Comment: Yes.So what i need to do for this any if a getting a JSON from a service then what is the way to store it.Shall is use ng-resource.

Comment: You could use ng-resource. If you want so take a look at the Credit Card Example in the [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). Alternatively you could use the $http service to post your new data to the server.

Comment: so if  create a json file  in project and get the data from there using angualr service and then using ng-resource will it work?

Comment: no, ng-resource is for interacting with a server. if you get your data from a local file you can't use it. But i higly recommend you to use a web server with your own API in order to get, post, update and delete your data. Otherwhise you need to edit your local json file every time you want to persist data.

Comment: Ok got it working thanks.Now i am getting data from a rest service and using ng-resource there and able to do the functionality i wanted.Thank a lot for your help @Daniel